# Show Android DialogFragment as dialog in portrait mode and as part of activity in landscape mode

Tags: android, fragment

Is it  possible to implement some kind of "self-managed" DialogFragment that display itslef like Dialog in portrait mode and like part of activity in landscape mode. It will be very greate if you present me with some code

Comment: I also have similar problem: How to display an full screen activity with Fragment in portrait, and the same Fragment as dialog in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
int orientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
    // Start DialogFragment as dialog
    MyFragmentDialog frag = new MyFragmentDialog();
    frag.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
else
{
    // Start activity that embeds DialogFragment
    Intent intent = new SimpleFragmentActivity.IntentBuilder(activity, MyFragmentDialog.class)
            .create();
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

`SimpleFragmentActivity` is a wrapper activity I wrote that simply embeds the fragment dialog in an activity for convenience, but basically you just need an activity that embeds MyFragmentDialog in it.  Here's the source for the wrapper activity: https://github.com/jt-gilkeson/fragment-utils